# How do I replace old PHP non functional functions with new PHP functions?

Tags: php, mysql

From one of my client I received an old database management website that was built around 6 to 7 yeas ago using PHP, now I need to add some features to it. The problem is that, its not working on local server, and I think the problem is with the old PHP code deterioration. Is there any simpler way that I could use to replace old PHP non functional functions with currently using functions of PHP, besides manually looking up in the code and replacing it? Which I find is very troublesome and leads to many new errors.

Is there any way I could make this process fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of scripts that would automatically update your PHP functions, and I would assume any script that advertises as such would be quite error-prone and end up causing even more errors.

Short of you just sitting down and doing it, you might check out a site like freelancer.com, because I bet you could pay some kid to do it for less than $30. It's not hard work, it's just tedious!

If you do end up doing it on your own, make sure your error reporting is on `STRICT` so you see everything.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such thing as an automated process to modernize old PHP code.

However, you can track the errors that PHP outputs and use a search/replace with regular expressions in your IDE or text editor to correct each type of error (as opposite to each single error).

It might take some time but from my experience it's the only and quickest way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would better to downgrade your PHP version to your clients version, then add new functionality, test it, and give it back to your costumer.

Never change things that are works correctly for years.